# Next js jest coverage

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I am using in my next js application Cypress and Jest. Running `jest --coverage` i get an error:

```js
STACK: Error: Duplicate plugin / preset detected.
If you 'd like to use two separate instances of a plugin,
they need separate names, e.g.

plugins: [
  ['some-plugin', {}],
  ['some-plugin', {}, 'some unique name'],
]
```

This is my .babelrc file:

```js
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["istanbul"]
}
```

Who faced with the same issue and how to solve it to get the coverage?

Comment: It's most likely due to `next/babel` preset and `istanbul` plugin adding a duplicated plugin. Do you actually need the `istanbul` plugin, though? Have you tried removing it from your `.babelrc` and re-running `jest --coverage`?

Comment: @juliomalves, i use instanbul for getting cypress coverage. If i remove it then everything works, but i still neet it for cypress. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: @juliomalves, also, could you take a look on this please. It will help me a lot.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71981432/testing-tools-for-reactjs-nextjs-application

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution that helped to solve the problem.
I had to add the env variable to the .babelrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "component": {
      "plugins": [
        "istanbul"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then add it to cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
const { devServer } = require('@cypress/webpack-dev-server');
const webpackConfig = require('./config/cypress.webpack.config.js');
const codeCoverageTask = require('@cypress/code-coverage/task');
module.exports = defineConfig({
viewportWidth: 1000,
viewportHeight: 660,
video: false,
env: {
  BABEL_ENV: 'component',
},
component: {
  devServer(devServerConfig) {
    return devServer({
      ...devServerConfig,
    framework: 'react',
    webpackConfig,
  });
  },
  specPattern: 'src/**/*.cy.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  codeCoverageTask(on, config);
  return config;
  },
  },
 });
```